# Access Nested inner join in a right join

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join, right-join

I am trying to nest an inner join in access inside a right join
The first right join query is

```
SELECT * FROM ProjectMilestone AS a
RIGHT JOIN ProjectMilestone AS b ON a.PredecessorMilestone = 
b.ProjectMilestoneID
```

Where when joined the first select statement would have d.MilestoneName

The second inner join query is

```
SELECT d.MilestoneName FROM ProjectMilestone AS c INNER JOIN Milestone AS d 
ON c.MilestoneID = d.MilestoneID
```

What I read with access is that there is an issue with just doing an inner join after the right join so I'm not sure what to do.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Sample Data:

```
ProjectMilestone Table
ProjectMilestoneID, MilestoneID, etc etc, PredecessorMilestone (which is linked to ProjectMilestoneID on a 0-1 to 1 cardinality)
79, 1 , , Null
80, 2, , 79
81, 3, , 80

Milestone Table
MilestoneID, MilestoneName
1, Handover
2, Deposit
3, Handover Panels
```

So the results I am after are:

```
Null 
Handover 
Deposit
```

So for second result (Handover): which in the ProjectMilestone Table is entry ProjectMilestoneID 80, the PredecessorMilestone is 79, then get the ProjectMilestoneID 79 via a right join to another instance of the ProjectMilestone Table (because it is linked to the same table) to find the MilestoneID value (1) from row where ProjectMilestoneID value 79, then find the corresponding MilestoneName entry in the Milestone Table for MilestoneID 1 Which is Handover.

Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Data and results updated.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. What does "Where when joined the first select statement would have d.MilestoneName" mean? Also your "results I am after" is not clear. Eg what is "ProjectMilestone2"? Tell us for a row (MilestoneName, ...) the conditon for it to be in the result.

Comment: I have attempted to make this more concise with an explanation of the second result in the results after. Removed other parts which caused confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't mix inner and outer joins like that.  You start with the table whose rows you want to keep.  Then add `LEFT JOIN`s for all the other tables.

If you want the milestone name for the first milestone, you can do:

```
SELECT pm.*, pmp.*, m.MilestoneName
FROM (ProjectMilestone AS pm LEFT JOIN
      ProjectMilestone AS pmp
      ON pm.PredecessorMilestone = pmp.ProjectMilestoneID
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Milestone AS m
     ON pm.MilestoneID = m.MilestoneID;
```

You can add another `LEFT JOIN` if you want the names of both milestones.

Comment: Updated, hopefully this is legible.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for updated query with new information?